# PowerShell variable changing date format

Tags: powershell, date

I have a PowerShell script that outputs to HTML which is changing the format of a returned date.

The code is as follows:

```
    $ResultSet = Get-DBADatabase -SQLInstance $SQLServerName | Select Name, Status, IsAccessible, RecoveryModel, SizeMB, Compatability, Collation, Owner, LastFullBackup, LastDiffBackup, LastLogBackup

    ForEach ($item in $ResultSet)
    {
        $HTML += "<TR>
           <TD>$($item.Name)</TD>
           <TD>$($item.Status)</TD>
           <TD>$($item.LastFullBackup)</TD>
           <TD>$($item.LastDiffBackup)</TD>
           <TD>$($item.LastLogBackup)</TD>
           <TD>$($item.IsAccessible)</TD>
           <TD>$($item.RecoveryModel)</TD>
           <TD>$($item.SizeMB)</TD>
           <TD>$($item.Compatability)</TD>
           <TD>$($item.Collation)</TD>
           <TD>$($item.Owner)</TD>
           </TR>"
    }
}
```

If I `write-host $item.LastFullBackup` the date is returned in Australian date format which is what I expect to get. Example: "14/12/2017 10:01:45"

But when I enclose the `$item.LastFullBackup` in the `<td>` in the HTML the resulting HTML page has changed the date to US date format, "12/14/2017 10:01:45".

From the research I have done I have tried converting to a date and back to string and formatting to string `$item.LastFullBackup.toString("dd/mm/yyyy")`, but nothing I have attempted has worked.

Comment: try just `<TD>$($item.LastFullBackup.ToString())</TD>`

Comment: By the way, you should try [`ConvertTo-Html`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html?view=powershell-5.1)